# converting a file to string then convert it to a file

Tags: java

i read a file and convert it to a string (for example .jpg to string )

then i write that String to file like ( example.jpg)

but windows said its broken file, and cant view that

whats wrong?

Comment: How are you converting the file to a string? That's almost certainly the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you that you take a look to the example in [Java Almanac](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.imageio/BasicImageRead.html), because you cannot read a image using `String`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a String to reliably hold binary data (such as an image), unless you're first encoding it to something like [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) - which is designed to represent any binary value within a String.  Otherwise, Strings are only designed to operate on a subset of byte values.  (For example, I can't really map a 0-byte value in a String without encoding - at least assuming something like ASCII or UTF-8.)

If you compare the bytes both before and after you did this, you will find that they are not the same.  Instead, use something like a byte array (`byte[] myImage`) to store your data.

Answer (score 1):

When converting the file to a string you'll be using an encoding, but not all encodings allow all byte combinations as valid characters. Therefore you've corrupted the jpeg when writing it out again, the invalid characters/byte combinations are usually either left out entirely or replaced with some thing like a question mark, which makes for an unhappy jpeg.